# Ubuntu 12.04 Fullscreen Video Dual Screen

Tags: video, flash, youtube

I recently starting getting this issue when making full screen videos.

So two things happen pretty consistently.

1. The video tries to fullscreen and fails and snaps back to window
2. Or it succeeds and the video is full screen on the entire length of the two monitors.

I would like for it to full screen on one of the monitor, preferably my main monitor. Right now what it thinks is that the system is one giant monitor which is useless.

So I wasn't clear I am talking about youtube, vimeo, flash based video in the browser.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Please update your answer to include what software you're using. Totem is the default.

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad look at the update :) sorry I wasn't clear.

Comment: You need to tell us: What browser (I assume Firefox), what video card and what X settings you have. For example are you using TwinView?

Comment: +1 Same problem here! For at least a week now. Using Google Chrome and 3 monitors with the default `Displays` handler on Mint 13 with Gnome-Shell. Hadn't had any problems till just last week or so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so the issue  I am having the newest flash plugin is causing the issue which version `11.3`

That being said what you need to do is go to `chrome://plugins` in your browser and disable all the flash plugin and re-enable the previous version which is `11.2`

Answer (score 0):

Right. So what happens is that when you fullscreen a Flash video player, it fills one of your screens, but if you try to interact with the other screen, then it drops out of fullscreen? That's well known and seriously annoying. I don't think there's any available fixes for it.

Comment: No. Thats not the issue. The issue it fails to fullscreen at all. and if it does succeed it takes up the space in between the two screens.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after installing a Chrome plugin for full screen Flash. I 'fixed' the problem by removing and reinstalling Chrome. I didn't need to delete the browser profile, just removing and reinstalling Chrome was enough.